# How can you transform a list into a string based upon the list length?

Tags: linq

This is an age-old problem for me I was hoping I could solve with linq.

Assume I have a List **foo** that has the letters A-E and I want to build a concatenation string string that looks like the following:

> a & b & c & d & e

This can construct the entire list, but has the extra " & " at the end

```
var myString = "";
foo.ForEach(x => myString += String.Format("{0} &  ", x));
```

I'd love to find a clean one line solution that will build this (minus the extra concatanator at the end, instead of having to write an extension method.

Comment: In pure Linq you can't. The goal of Linq is to return sets of data, not to flatten it. You will have to use classic join methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var concatstring = String.Join("&", foo);
```

Comment: Oh my.  Wish I knew about this a while ago.

Comment: Yeah, there's all sorts of neat things that no one seems to know of. I've been a developer for 8 years and I only learned about this a year ago or so.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing it to a `string[]` and then `join`ing it?

```
List<string> foo;
// ...
string joinedString = string.Join(" & ", foo.ToArray());

// or, as vc 74 pointed out below, in .NET 4+ you can do
string joinedString = string.Join(" & ", foo);
```

Comment: string.Join has an overload which accepts an IEnumerable<string> since .net 4

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can do it using Aggregate. String.Join is better, but there's a comment saying LINQ can't do this sort of thing, so...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAggregate()
    {
        List<string> input = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C"};
        string output = input.Aggregate((list, next) => list + " & " + next);
        Assert.AreEqual(output, "A & B & C");
    }
```